# Removing one element from jquery sortable list on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have two sortable lists in jQuery. They're called sortable1 and sortable2. They are <li>s in <ul>s. When the user drags an element from sortable2 into sortable1, the element clones in sortable2. Once dropped in sortable1, the user shouldn't be able to move it back into sortable2 because there is already another one that took it's place.

My question is essentially two fold:

1. How do I prevent an item dropped in sortable1 from being dragged back into sortable2 while still having the ability to rearrange.
2. How can I impliment the click function so that it will delete the sortable element you click on. This behavior should only occur in sortable1.

Here is the script:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable1" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();
            $( "#sortable2" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
                    helper: function(e,li) {
                                    copyHelper= li.clone().insertAfter(li);
                                    return li.clone();
                                }
    }).disableSelection();
});    
</script>
```

And here is the snippet of html behind the lists:

```
<div id="symbolbay">
     <p>Drop symbols here</p>
     <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable"></ul>
</div>
<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Click me to delete only me</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Click me to delete only me</li>
...There are a whole bunch more, finally ending in...
</ul>
```

Thanks for any help! I am new to this amazing technology and I am continually amazed at what it can do.

Comment: Can you include some CSS?  Seeing this without any styling makes it hard to follow.

Comment: @ChrisHerbert  what does CSS have to do with sorting logic?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/R8cTb/ just for what i understand, this make sense? have in mind that you have to differenciate the two lists in some point

Comment: Nothing, but if you paste the code into a jsfiddle without CSS, it's hard to tell what's going on. Make it easier for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably split this into two questions.  Regarding #2:

```
$('#sortable1 .ui-state-highlight').click(function(){
  $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: This works really well. How can I do this with the clones? Where would I put the .addClass if necessary? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. Thanks for the help! I split this up into two questions as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code (@ChrisHerbert code does not work in my case):

```
$("#sortable").on("click", "li", function () {
    $(this).remove();
});
```